# Why is $\displaystyle\int^{1/2}_{-1/2} \cos(\tfrac{2}{3} \pi x)\, dx= 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is 
$$\int^{1/2}_{-1/2} \cos\left(\frac{2}{3} \pi x\right)\, dx= 0\qquad ?$$

Because mathematically, we have
$$\sin\left( \frac{2}{3}\pi \right) - \sin\left(-\frac{2}{3}\pi\right) = 2\sin\left(\frac{2}{3}\pi\right)$$ instead.

And what about

$$\int^{1/2}_{-1/2} \sin\left(\frac{2}{3} \pi x\right) \,dx $$
What is this equal to ?

I know this sounds like a very dumb question. But i would like to see different approaches to tackle this problem.

Comment: The sine integral must be $0$, as sine is an odd function.

Comment: Can you elaborate a litte bit more please? So whenever we encounter an odd function , their area is always zero ???

Comment: If the bounds of integration are $-a$ and $a$, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

We know, $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$$

$$\int_{-a}^a\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}3\right)dx$$
$$=\int_{-a}^a\sin\left(\frac{2\pi (a-a-x)}3\right)dx$$
$$=\int_{-a}^a\sin\left(-\frac{2\pi x}3\right)dx$$
$$=-\int_{-a}^a\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}3\right)dx\text{ as }\sin(-x)=-\sin x$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
If $f$ is an even function (resp. odd function) on the interval $[-a,a]$ then
$$\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=2\int_0^af(x)dx\quad \mathrm{(resp.}=0)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}\cos\frac{2}{3}\pi x\,dx=\left.\frac{3}{2\pi}\sin\frac{2}{3}\pi x\right|_{-1/2}^{1/2}=\frac{3}{2\pi}\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{3}-\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right)=$$

$$=\frac{3}{\pi}\sin\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{3\sqrt 3}{2\pi}\neq 0$$

Comment: ...and the serial, anonymous downvoter strikes again. Oh, well...:)